# How to change component css with props with Nuxt Js Vue js

Tags: css, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-props

I'm new to Nuxt and Vue, thanks for being indulgent ;).
I have a "Subtitle" component that I use in another "Main" component (names are for the example).

How can I change the css of the "subtitle" component from the "Main" component ?

*Here "Subtitle" component* :

```
<template>
    <div>
       <h1 :class="data">{{ title }}</h1>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: 'subtitle',
    props: {
        title: String,
    }
}
</script>
```

*And here my "Main" component :*

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <Subtitle :title="title""></Subtitle>           
    </div>
</template>
```

I searched with the props etc.... But now I've been on it for a while and I'm blocking.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using the combination of props and computed

Subtitle Component

```
<template>
    <div>
       <h1 :style="getStyle">{{ title }}</h1>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: 'subtitle',
    props: {
        stylings: Object,
    },
   computed: {
    getStyle() {
      return this.stylings;
    }
   }
}
</script>
```

Main Component

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <Subtitle :stylings="customStyle"></Subtitle>           
    </div>
</template>
export default {
    name: 'subtitle',
    data() {
        return {
          customStyle: {
              'font-weight': 'Bold',
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I didn't know it's cool, I learned something today.

Comment: Great, if that pls do consider giving an upvote..thanks :)